Lightning layout horizontal alignment Issue
I am trying to align the component layout as pictured below but I am not successful yet. It appears that I am missing to make use of layout and layout item using horizontal align but not sure how to achieve it.

<template>
<lightning-layout horizontal-align="center">
    <lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit Changes" title="Submit Changes" onclick={handleSubmit}
            class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
<lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" vertical-align="stretch">
    <lightning-layout-item size="12">
        <Strong>
            <lightning-layout vertical-align="start">
                <template for:each={notesheaderList} for:item="notesheader">
                    <lightning-layout-item size="2" key={notesheader.key}>
                        <p>{notesheader}</p>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </Strong>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12">
        <template for:each={departmentList} for:item="department">
            <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" horizontal-align="start" key={department.key}>
                <strong>{department}</strong>
                <template for:each={notesfieldList} for:item="f" for:index="index">
                    <lightning-layout-item multiple-rows="true" horizontal-align="start" size={f.size} key={f.Id}>
                        <lightning-input if:false={f.isPicklist} data-index={index} name={f.name} label={f.label}
                            type={f.type} value="">
                        </lightning-input>
                        <lightning-select if:true={f.isPicklist} name="hyg_osp_notes" size={f.size}
                            value={hygospnotes} options={ospnotesoptions} onchange={handleHygNotesChange}
                            data-index={index}>
                        </lightning-select>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class Pds_OSPLwcComponent extends LightningElement {
gpospnotes = '';
hygospnotes = '';
@track ospcheck;
@track uspcheck;
@track nacheck;
departmentList = ["General Practice", "Hygiene", "Perio", "Endo", "Ortho","Pediatics","Oral Surgery"];
notesheaderList = ["Location Type","OSP", "USP", "N/A", "OSP Notes","Requested Deviations"];
notesfieldList  = [
    {required:"false",type:"checkbox",fieldname:"osp",size:"1"},
    {required:"false",type:"checkbox",fieldname:"usp",size:"1"},
    {required:"false",type:"checkbox",fieldname:"na",size:"1"},
    {required:"false",type:"picklist",fieldname:"ospnotes",size:"1"},
    {required:"false",type:"text",fieldname:"requesteddeviations",size:"2"}
];

connectedCallback() {        
    this.notesfieldList = this.notesfieldList.map(field => ({...field, isPicklist: field.type === 'picklist' }));
}

get ospnotesoptions() {
    return [
        { label: 'choose one...', value: '' },
        { label: 'Choice 1', value: 'Choice 1' },
        { label: 'Choice 2', value: 'Choice 2' },
        { label: 'Choice 3', value: 'Choice 3' },
    ];
}

}
